# ms access form listbox changing whole field

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have created a form to update a query that that is in turn based on a master table containing information on a number of files. This master table is then related to several other tables in say for example a table called `group_table`, defining which group the file would belong to, which contains an `ID` field and the `group_name`. This is then related in a one-to-many relationship with the master table based on the `group.ID` and a field in the master table `master_table.group` and joined in the query the form is based on.

In the form I have designated a listbox control to update the `group` field of the query/master table. The contents available for selection in the list box were set based on the `group_name` field from the `group_table` table which is defined in the RowSouce section of the property sheet of the form.

So my issue is that when I try and update any records in the query using the listbox in the form, all of the records that are the same will get changed as well. E.g., changing a record in one row from "Group A" to "Group B" will change all the records containing "Group A" to "Group B" in the `group` field. So I was wondering if there is anything I can do to set it so only the specific record that I want to change gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

When you are making the call to update the table you should make sure that you are using `WHERE` along with the primary key to make sure that you update that row only. An example would be a statement similar to the one below.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [group_table] AS G INNER JOIN [master_table] AS M 
ON G.[ID] = M.[groupID] 
SET G.[group] = '"& Group A & "' 
WHERE M.[groupID] = '" & groupIDFromForm & "';"
```

Apply the `ON` from the join so that the foreign key and primary key are going to share the same value, and from there use the form to create a variable that you can use to identify the exact row. From there the program should execute the query correctly.